# Page redirect to next page

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am using a map api in my app.For selecting marker, button named "`Add marker`" and "`Refresh map"` for refresh map.I am facing the here.

After saving the data,the save button will redirect to next page.in my case,both "Add marker",`"Refresh map"` both are doing the save buttons job and if i press `"Add marker"` instead of showing marker,page gets redirect to next page.this is happening after using the `</form>`.see my template here,

```
<form method="POST" action="/member/where/" >
{% csrf_token %}
<td colspan="2" class="incident-type" style="padding-left:25px">
  {% for location in locationList%}
  {% if location.parent_location_id == None %}
  <h1>{{location.title}}</h1>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<p>
<span class="map_buttons" >{% include "buttons/refreshmap.html" %}</span> <span class="map_buttons" style="margin-left:20px;">{% include "buttons/addmarker.html" %} </span>
</p>
<p id=ir-nextbtn>{% include "buttons/next.html" %}</a></form></p>
```

refreshmarker.html

```
<button type="submit" title="Refresh map"  class="map_buttons button_style">Refresh map</button>
```

addmarker.html

```
<button type="submit" title="Add marker"  class="map_buttons button_style">Add marker</button>
```

Need clarification about this issue.

Comment: can you paste the html for the button aswell? are both buttons submit buttons?

Comment: @Rhea ,both html,updated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because both the buttons are of type `submit`, when you click either of the buttons, the form gets submitted. as a result, the page gets redirected oto `action` of the form i.e. /member/where/

try this:-
keep the refresh as it is,

```
  <button type="submit" title="Refresh map"  class="map_buttons button_style">Refresh map</button>
```

and add

```
 <button onClick=somefuntion(this)' title="Add marker"  class="map_buttons button_style">Add   marker</button>
```

and let some function do the needfull

```
<script>
function somefuntion(button){
    // your code
   document.forms[0].submit() // this will submit your form
 }
</script>
```